# Erro no gradle Android Studio - .gradle\buildOutputCleanup\cache.properties (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Galera ontem estava rodando normal meu projeto no Android Studio, ai hoje vou abrir e o projeto não sincroniza, primeiro tive um erro com o ".gradle/caches/4.6/scripts" ai pesquisei e falaram para apagar essa pasta e dar rebuild no projeto que o Android Studio iria criar ela de novo, fiz isso, mas agora estou recebendo o seguinte erro ".gradle\buildOutputCleanup\cache.properties (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)" Novamente fui pesquisar e disseram para apagar esse arquivo também, mas a questão é que essa pasta nem existe aqui, agora não sei mais o que fazer, também não faço ideia do porque deu esses erros da noite pro dia, se alguém puder me ajudar vou ficar muito grato.

Comment: claro. você apagou o arquivo, não dá pra encontrar. por isso indico sempre compiladores online.

Comment: pra seu android studio voltar a funcionar reinstale ele.